# Should I keep my 5-year-old electric tank heater as a storage unit if I am about to install a new gas tankless heater?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, tankless

A plumber recently told me that its perfectly common to keep the old 40 gallon tank water heater in series with a new tankless water heater.

The motivation is to decrease the time it takes to get hot water to a faucet. And also to then have endless hot water once it gets there.

As I understand  it, the tankless pumps hot water into the cold water inlet of the tank heater, and that in turn pumps out to the house via its hot outlet. The hot water either waits in the tank (*which adds heat to keep temp constant*) or passes through if a faucet is.

Heating happens in the tankless unit, and is maintained in the tank unit until use.

Does this make sense to do?

Comment: When you state “task” heater I think of a small 5 gallon or less at the point of use in this case yes it is common to keep them for instant hot water especially when at the far end of a house. If full sized located close to the tankless it would defeat the purpose of a tankless.

Comment: If you are going with a tankless, is there some problem you anticipate that this set up will address?

Comment: Perhaps it was to be used as a tempering tank, by being upstream of the tankless? Just to sit there, collect ambient heat in the summer?

Comment: I [edit]ed all "thankess" to "tankless". We do routine edits like this all the time... it's a tankless job, but I don't mind :)

Comment: I am very tankful for your help.

Comment: Isn't the whole purpose of a tankless heater is to do away with a holding tank? A holding tank that needs to be re-heated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is

> Does this make sense to do?

My answer to that is, Based on how you worded your scenario, This does **not make sense to me.** I can not wrap my head around how it would be in parallel. **What you have described is two units in series**. (*one after the other*)

A tankless water heater is an on demand unit. It only fires up and heats water when a hot water faucet is opened.

If they were in series:

If the "tank", installed after the tankless, is not heating water  then all the water in it will be cold. **(*if it is heating water then what is the point of having the tankless*)**

When you open the hot water faucet the tankless will fire up and start sending hot water to the faucet but it will have to push all of the cold water in the tank out through the faucet BEFORE any HOT water gets to the faucet.

Comment: Thank you. I made edits based on your answer.

Comment: Thanks but it does not clear anything up for me. Why have a tankless feeding a tank?

Comment: "*Heating happens in the thankless one, and maintained in the tank one until use.*" This defeats the purpose of having a tankless.

Comment: Right.. I thought if thankless has a high start up time, this was the point? Although, perhaps the high start up time comes from the distance traveled by the water, not how long it takes for the tankless to start up?

Comment: Correct, the tankless starts making hot water immediately, it has to push any cold water in  the line out first before hot is available at the faucet.

Comment: I suppose in theory you could do it the other way around. Tank heater first set at a low temp, sending that warmed water  to the tankless so the tankless does not have to work that hard. But that is still  a needless use of energy, which is, *usually*, why you go with a tankless in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. I was reading more about this. Maybe what I need is a recirculating pump and faucet valve? Pump that can be activated on a schedule?

Comment: Do a search, There are several questions on here about  recirculating pumps for both tankless and tanks systems.  Good luck

Comment: Reading more about this, perhaps tank was to be used as a tempering tank, by being upstream of the tankless? Just to sit there, collect ambient heat in the summer?

Comment: The tank is very well insulated. It is not going to absorb usable amounts of heat from its surroundings. If you used the tank heater upstream of the tankless without the electric power, then there would be no significant "tempering" (warming of the intake water before it would go into the tankless). If you used the electric power to warm the water in the tank, then what temp would you set the tank to? A tank is supposed to be set at 140 F (60 C) to prevent bacterial growth. MAYBE you could set the tank to say 70 t o 80 F, which could help if your intake water is very cold, but . . .

Comment: 140 F might be too hot for input into a tankless heater. If your intake water is very cold then warming it to say 75 F would definitely increase the output of the tankless heater but this would only last as long as the tank was emptied of warmed water. And tanks finally leak and usually when you are not home causing water damage.

Answer (score 3):

Your core concern is the amount of time it takes between opening the hot faucet and getting water that is actually hot.  **This plan will do nothing for that**.

The delay is caused by the volume of water (inventory) that is in the pipe in between the water heater and the faucet.  That pipe is exposed to ambient? Outside? air, and has cooled off. That water must be physically pushed out of the pipe by hot water. It's like a big plunger.

You can figure out the inventory of water in the pipe by taking its interior cross section x its length.  For instance 50' of 1/2" pipe* contains 0.57 gallons of (now cold) water. Going out a 1.5 GPM low flow showerhead, it will take 23 seconds for that to *vamonos*.

The cure is to make the pipe routing more direct, smallify it, or move the heater closer to the faucet. Each step down in pipe size reduces pipe volume by *about* half (and thus wait time) - however, too small and that restricts flow too much.

Restricting flow can *actually help* tanklesses, because a major customer-satisfaction issue with tankless is when the customer draws water faster than the tankless is able to heat it satisfactorily, so they get tepid water - and the customer does not understand the technology, so they refuse to do the one thing that'll fix it -- to reduce flow rate. So they reach impasse and blame it on the tankless.

Note that a tankless->tank arrangement will only make this problem worse, because the tanked heater will assure the first 40 gallons is OK, then will put a 40-gallon "delay" between action and consequence. So as hard as it is already for customers to connect "reducing flow" to "increasing temperature", this "40 gallon delay" will be far more confusing.  I would expect bizarre customer-satisfaction issues with this.

Putting the tankless *after* the tank would mean you can ignore flow rate issues until the tank empties, as the tankless will not operate at all.  Once the tank goes tepid, the tankless will be doing "all the heavy lifting", and then flow rate will affect heat. Again, very complicated, you shouldn't have to take a training class to understand your water heater.

---

---

* 1/2" squared x pi/4 = 0.2 square inches or 0.00137 square feet.... x 50' = 0.06 square feet.... x 8.33 gal/sq.ft. = 0.569 gal.

Answer (score 2):

There are tankless heaters designed to operate in conjunction with a storage tank, but the old tank heater would not work for this use. And a basic standard tankless water heater does not have the controls to work in conjunction with a storage tank.

There are published designs for using an electric tank water heater as a storage tank in conjunction with a tankless heater, but they require several extra valves and controls.